# JS redirect user based on a remote files existence

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to redirect a user based on the existence of a remote file. I'm not sure if this is even possible.

The code in website.com:

```
var result = doesFileExist("http://remote-website.com/verifier.php");
 if (result == true) {
    header("Location: https://website.com/"); 
} else {
    header("Location: https://website.com/error.php"); 
}
```

I see this error on the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: doesFileExist is not defined

Comment: Can we see the `doesFileExist` method?

Comment: `function doesFileExist(urlToFile) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('HEAD', urlToFile, false);
    xhr.send();
     
    if (xhr.status == "404") {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}`

Comment: @GokulaKannanT this is the one. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way would be to send a GET request to the page, and check if the response code is 404 (not found):

```
fetch(url)
.then(function(response) {
  var status = response.status; //the response code, e.g. 200, 404, ...
  if(status == 404) {
    //do something
  }
});
```

Note that some websites automatically redirect you to a default error page if the requested file does not exist, and in that case the response code you get may not be a 404.